# Unraring partial files

Tags: command-line, rar

I have several directories within a rar file. I am looking to only extract a certain directory out of the rar with cli.

ex: in a rar 
/tmp
/home
/etc

I only want to extract the /home directory

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the `unrar` program most linuxes have, it's

```
unrar x foo.rar home
```